# Salesforce:bug? Allows importing of more characters in long text area than it can handle

Tags: data-loader

text area long has size of 32768 characters.

When we import data(using data loader) more than 32768 characters in text area(long), SF does allow import. However when we try to edit that text area, SF show error 'x characters more ' on UI while saving record.

Why does SF allow more than 32768 characters in long text area?
How to restrict data loader from importing such data?

OR

I am doing something terribly wrong?

Dataloader version:-20.0(if that matters)
Used bulk API.

Comment: Nice catch Ganesh!

Comment: Is this a "Long Text Field", or "Long Text Field (Rich)"? Maybe there's a limit on the UI's capability to load text? I'm not familiar with any such limit, but I've never intentionally loaded large amounts of text into it, either.

Comment: It is "Long Text Field".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an API header called [AllowFieldTruncationHeader](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_header_allowfieldtruncation.htm), that allows an integration to ignore the maximum defined storage limit of a field. When set to true, values that would exceed the limit are truncated to the maximum length of the field. When set to false, the default behavior, truncation isn't allowed and the transaction fails (or partially succeeds, if the AllOrNoneHeader is set to false as well).

The default data loader build permits truncation. You can change this default behavior by opening the settings menu on the Data Loader, and turning off "Allow Field Truncation". To get to the settings menu, launch the Data Loader, cancel the initial dialog screen, then click on Settings > Settings.

Comment: Also 32768 is not a hard limit. You can have salesforce increase this to as much as 128k characters by opening a case.

Comment: Excellent point, but regardless of the actual limit, the point is that you can control if the data is truncated or an error is generated.

Comment: Using, Allow Field Truncation option I am able to enable/disable truncation. 

But still I am not able to figure out why do I get the error 'x characters more' on UI while editing record. 
I tried fetching the data using workbench to get the data size that's saved, and its below max limit. Its displayed on the SF page too, but when I open the field in edit mode, it gives me the error 'x characters more'.